# Switching between Activities without creating dependencies

Tags: android, performance

I'm working with a codebase that contains several (10+) Activities.  Each Activity class has the ability to launch every other Activity in the project.  In the code this looks like startActivityA(), startActivityB(), etc....  So there is a lot of duplication as well as dependencies in the code.

My question is this: Is there anything wrong with creating a class (possibly even an Activity) that acts as a Navigation Controller for all of the other activities?  So when Activity A wants to launch Activity B, it can call this class with (maybe passing in a String "B") and then THAT class will launch the Activity.  Activity A & B would no longer be dependent on each other, and there would be much less code.

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html. Use action bar. Check the link

Comment: it almost sounds like you should either put these activity launchers in a `menu` or an `action bar`. However without a little better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to say. Also if this is the case then you want to look into `fragments` as well

Comment: The project has a custom made ActionBar, not the standard one from the SDK.  Since each screen has a dropdown menu, each screen has to be able to go to every other screen in the app.  When you click an item in the dropdown menu, it asks the current Activity to switch to the new Activity.

Comment: Thanks IrishWhiskey, that's what I was thinking.  Either have the side menu launch the Activity or have a Navigation class that "governs" the Activities.

Comment: I have a custom ActionBar also and extend my `Activities` from a `BaseActivity` or `BaseListActivity` depending on what I need. I used `Flags` and keep most of the code in these `BaseActivities` to open a new `Activvity` from a dropdown populated from a `menu.xml` also...works perfectly

Comment: Ah,okay.  I'm using a BaseActivity as well. I'm going to try putting the Activity code in there.  Thanks!

Comment: @MartyMiller no problem, it sounds like you know where to go from here then. Simply list all your `activities` via `intents` inside the `menu` or `fragments` inside the `actionbar`. There is a ton of information in these forums about this if you need help.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help. I can give you an example of how I did it to cut down on duplicate code when creating the `Intents`

Answer (score 1):

A possibly simpler way to achieve your goals may be just to use `Intent Flags`. You can use the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` so if the `Activity` is already on the stack then a new instance won't be created. There won't be any dependency or redundancy with this

[Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

I assume you know how to set `Flags` in an `Intent` but if not

```
    intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
    startActivity(intent);
```